# Tabulating between containers

Tags: windows-7, focus

Using <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it is possible to change focus between controls. However, in several cases - the most notable for me being Windows compiled help files - they only change focus between controls inside a single container; either one with tabs (search/contents/favourites) or content panel, where the help itself is shown.

What I would like to know is whether it is possible to tabulate/change focus between containers/panels? As it stands, I find myself at loss as to how to explore content of the help document without using the mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try F6.

F6 is the Shell command to switch between panes.  Since IE, Explorer and Help viewer share similar DLLs, this should work.

This isn't guaranteed to work on other apps though.